# How to add or remove woocommerce error messages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing this shipping cost generator for TNT as a WordPress woo-commerce extention.the thing is if there is an error i need to show the error and restrict user from checkout.I used following method to do that.
The problem is how i can remove this notice when the user entered the correct data and manage the thing done.

```
if (!empty($xml->ratedTransitTimeResponse->ratedProducts->ratedProduct[0]->quote->price)) {
    $cost+= (float)$xml->ratedTransitTimeResponse->ratedProducts->ratedProduct[0]->quote->price;
}
else wc_add_wp_error_notices(new WP_Error(1, 'Shipping cost error'));
```

When user entered correct data user can proceed but still the error is there. I need to remove it!

(I tried this far with lot of references so if I have missed anything, please correct me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

woo-commerce has their own predefined functions for this which i didn't know at that time.used wc_add_notice and wc_clear_notices solved the issue!

```
if(!empty($xml->ratedTransitTimeResponse->ratedProducts->ratedProduct[0]->quote->price)){

     $cost+=(float)$xml->ratedTransitTimeResponse->ratedProducts->ratedProduct[0]->quote->price;
     wc_clear_notices();
}                       
else
{   //wc_add_wp_error_notices(new WP_Error(1,'Shipping cost error'));
     wc_clear_notices();
     wc_add_notice( 'Shipping cost error', 'error' );
}
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i updated it now hope it will be helpful.thank you!