# Avoid checkout for specific products on specific country in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, country

**Here's what I want to do:**
If customer selects Canada as shipping country and there's a specific product in cart, checkout should not happen and an error message should generate informing customer of why checkout didn't happen.

**My research:**
[Add or remove woocommerce error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37043382/add-or-remove-woocommerce-error-messages) has code to generate WooCommerce error messages. I asked a question yesterday that gave me codes to check if certain product is in cart and if shipping country is set to Canada [Remove Canada from country list when specific products are in cart on Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53321692/remove-canada-from-country-list-when-specific-products-are-in-cart-on-woocommerc) I am not sure which filter/action I must hook my code to so it runs whenever "Place Order" is clicked on checkout page.

**Update:**
So I tried combining the two codes I have listed in **my research** but it didn't work. Any help if I need to approach this differently will be really appreciated
Product IDs are 15631 & 12616

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using the action hook `woocommerce_check_cart_items` through this custom function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'products_not_shipable_in_canada' );
function products_not_shipable_in_canada() {
    // Only on checkout page (allowing customer to change the country in cart shipping calculator)
    if( ! is_checkout() ) return;

    // Set your products
    $products = array(15631, 12616);

    // Get customer country
    $country = WC()->session->get('customer')['shipping_country'];
    if( empty($country) ){
        $country = WC()->session->get('customer')['billing_country'];
    }
    // For CANADA
    if( $country == 'CA' ){
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $item ){
            // IF product is in cart
            if( in_array( $item['product_id'], $products ) ){
                // Avoid checkout and display an error notice
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( 
                    __("The product %s can't be shipped to Canada, sorry.", "woocommerce" ),  
                    '"' . $item['data']->get_name() . '"'
                ), 'error' );
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Related: [Set minimum allowed weight for a specific country in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066649/set-minimum-allowed-weight-for-a-specific-country-in-woocommerce/52067456#52067456)

Comment: thank you, this works perfectly. I have a question though: can I have the product title in the error message so customer will know which product can't be shipped to Canada

Comment: @DanishMuneer Updated… please check it.